# Get function result or value from an object by property

Tags: typescript, conditional-types

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEBLAdgFxDAZlMCCCADgfAN4CwAUPPMlALYgBc8AFAJTwC8AfPAM6oYKAOaVqANwx9EAe2TMBQ5KKpJgzZAFc6AIwyUAvpUpg5A+MJCoACjBnFO8TJuRhUs5AB4AwvBAAPdGRgPnhCAgAaeABlP0CQYNCAaxAATxlMMKJuFlM0ANRmbyiCOwJmaI4igG1ogF04oJDWADo22GE+ZihkVOq6jh54HtT4AH54ACUrTRhkABVUghAfWrreGvrSMXg88wZUAAsZYC5duXRA6tL7OoBuHcRMllQlkAz4A+PTzl-4AHJnK53HJ-hxyKpqHBULNkJ8rN92A9VAY-BA+AgIdQoTM5vCjidkdQjBQDMjKKBILAEOJYMMiPBmOFyRRLDYyiwoEQogAiRDAHkcAD0Qq4vC0un0rKstnsnO58B5tAYgvgIrF-EEIkobNlBHlkUVkhg0jkqvVQ0U2ooQA)

I'm trying to figure out the correct type for a utility function `getProp` that will index an object by key and return the primitive value at that index or the result of the function at that index.

```js
declare interface App {
  name: () => string
  version: string
  id: number
}

const getProp = function<C extends App, S extends keyof App>(context: C, prop: S) : C[S] extends (...args: any[]) => any ? ReturnType<C[S]> : C[S] {
  const method = context[prop];
  if (typeof method === 'function') {
    return method(); // Error: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'C[S] extends (...args: any[]) => any ? ReturnType<C[S]> : C[S]'.
  } else {
    return method; // Error: Type '() => string' is not assignable to type 'C[S] extends (...args: any[]) => any ? ReturnType<C[S]> : C[S]'.
  }
};

declare var app : App;

// These are all correct despite the errors
getProp(app, "id") // => number
getProp(app, "name") // => string
getProp(app, "version") // => string
```

The type presented here "works" but TypeScript is giving me errors on the lines indicated. Is there a better way to type this properly without errors or should I just drop in my old friend `//@ts-ignore`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When we use `Generic Functions` the actual type instantiation happens when we invoke it, `getProp<App, 'name'>`

Hence the Typescript compiler needs to be sure that the types we are using must be compatible and follow the constraints.

Since the Return Type of `getProp` is conditional we can make use of assertion/aliasing to inform the typescript compiler of the state in which this branch will be reached

In your code, the compiler was complaining that it is possible that you are returning some code (which might not match the return value) at the time of declaration!

Hence by aliasing it, we make sure that the types will be of this ReturnType only!

To avoid Repetition I created a new type alias `PropReturnType<T>`

```
declare interface App {
  name: () => string
  version: string
  id: number
}

type PropReturnType<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends (...args: any[]) => any ? ReturnType<T[K]> : T[K] }


const getProp = function<C extends App, S extends keyof C>(context: C, prop: S): PropReturnType<C>[S]{
  const method = context[prop];
  if (typeof method === 'function') {
    return method();
  } else {
    return method as PropReturnType<C>[S];
  }
};



declare var app: App;

getProp(app, "id") // => number
getProp(app, "name") // => string
getProp(app, "version") // => string
```

[CODE PLAYGROUND](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEBLAdgFxDAZlMCCCADgfAN4CwAUPPMlALYgBc8AFAJTwC8AfPAM6oYKAOaVqANwx9EAe2TMBQ5KKpJgzZAFc6AIwyUAvpUqoAngQQAFGDIIAlEKk0xkAFXMgAPK96dS8AG0AaSRkeABrEFMZTHhXAF1mV2D4%20BAAD3RkYD5WADoC2GE%20ZihkUwD4jh54MtN4AH54BycXdwtvFN4klPgjCmMKMDkBeGFHa1sueExNZDBUWWRPAGE0zJBs3MICABp4AGV1rJyIqJj4Fe4WYbQM1GYV-YIbAmYDtmZJ%200dnNw9VtwAgd4uRVLdRgxUAALGTAaa3dCZAIvWzxADcYiQsRYZgsFyhsPhnBJ8AA5LN5os5GSOGDqNQ4K0woS4exMaoDGkIHwEPSGUy-vBWfCoLlvi0-u0vFdgRisf0DBzBpRQJBYAhxLBakR4MwdsqKONUN8WFAiPsAESIYCWjgAentXF4Wl0%20iNE1eZot8EttAYdvgjud-EEIkoxtN5r2vskMGkckDwZqinDFCAA)

Comment: After checking around and verifying some cases. Seemingly, this answer fits the above question

Comment: @Bishwajit jha Neat solution! +1, How do you decide to go with object approach for the `PropReturnType`? In other words, how do you decide to do `PropReturnType<C>[S]` and not `PropReturnType<C, S>`.. I tried the latter but never struck me to use the former so

Comment: @tanmay Thanks :)
Yeah both of them should work correctly!
I just used the `Indexed Access`  Directly on the `PropReturnType<C>`, because it would just be repetitive to write the constraints in type alias again when the `getProp()` already has that.
Just in case you wanna see how the latter approach would look [Code Link](https://tsplay.dev/wgg39w)

Comment: @Bishwajitjha cool, I was actually going for not needing the `[K in keyof T]` part at all.. [like this](https://tsplay.dev/WYk7rN)

Comment: Oh yes, fair enough, we can save on that `[K in keyof T]` mapping over part. 
Though I just started with a general solution by using mapped types just in case some other transformations were required. But in this case, we can just directly use conditional type!
Also, both of the solutions would be equally good from the performance point of view anyway because `Indexed access` types are evaluated `cold/ lazily` i.e. Only the key which we are indexing gets computed